# What is the proper method to become able to connect conduit signals inside Qsys?

Tags: quartus

Qsys (now known as Platform designer) identifies Avalon MM, Avalon ST, Clock, Reset and some other type of interfaces and makes it trivial to be able to connect them between different blocks. However, although I have read that conduits are not supported intrinsically by Qsys, it is possible to be able to connect conduits together between different modules within Qsys. My question is, if two modules have conduit signals, some of which need to be connected together, how do we do it properly? The basic idea is that the required conduit signals themself are connected between different modules within Qsys and do not have to be exported and then connected outside in an RTL block.

Answer (score 1):

All the Conduit signals are shown with connection points in the same column.

If you select one of these, a new column is created where just this one signal is routeable, and setting a second connection point in that column then creates the connection.